# Redirect page on particular error when validation failed in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am creating single page website which have different sections and one of then is signup page, When i submit form without entering values then it shows errors but page does not load on that section, Page stuck above. I want when validation fails then page need to redirect on that particular error.

**Example**: If I did not fill firstname but filled lastname then page need to redirect on firstname directly.

```
 // Controller
 if($this->form_validation->run() == false) 
    {
            $data=array();
            $base = array();
            $data['whatsinside']=$this->load->view(codeg_front_version('whatsinside'), '', true);
            $data['signup']= $this->load->view(codeg_front_version('signup'), '', true);
            $base['custom'] = 'home';
            codeg_base($data,$base,true,true,true); 
}
else
{
   Redirect to thank you page
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label class="form-control-placeholder" for="fname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control form-text" value="<?=set_value('fname')?>" required />
<div class="error-msg"><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label class="form-control-placeholder" for="lname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" class="form-control form-text" value="<?=set_value('lname')?>" required />
<div class="error-msg"><?php echo form_error('lname'); ?></div>                                                         
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 clear">
<label class="form-control-placeholder" for="pnric">NRIC</label>
<input type="text" id="pnric" name="pnric" class="input-nric form-control form-text" value="<?=set_value('pnric')?>" maxlength="9" required />
<div class="error-msg"><?php echo form_error('pnric'); ?></div>
</div>                                              
<div class="form-group col-md-6 gender">
<label class="col-md-2 gsb-label-light" for="pnric">Gender</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="gsb-radios">Male
          <input class="form-check-input gsb-radio" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" <?php echo set_radio('gender', 'Male'); ?> />
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="gsb-radios">Female
          <input class="form-check-input gsb-radio" type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" <?php echo set_radio('gender', 'Female'); ?> />
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>                                                                
    </div>
</div>
<div class="error-msg clear"><?php echo form_error('gender'); ?></div>
```

[image]
when come to the fail condition then redirect to same page but on particular error.

Comment: please add sample code: view and controller

Comment: No, I have already read that article. Thanks @vasilenicusor

Comment: use if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {
            redirect('same_page#anchor');
        }  and in your view  <?php echo validation_errors()?>

Comment: take a look on this https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-63396.html

Comment: I also tried this one but redirects stuck in loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
// check form validation only on POST action
if ($this->input->post('submit') == 'save') {
    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == TRUE) {
        // form is valid
        // save data and redirect to thank you page
        redirect('thank_you_page');
    } else {
        // we have errors
        // redirect to specific page section
        redirect('same_page#error_section');
    }

}
```

You need to have the action button like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
    Save
</button>
```

**Edit 2**

On validation error, you need to get first invalid input and redirect this specific input id

```
// check form validation only on POST action
if ($this->input->post('submit') == 'save') {
    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == TRUE) {
        // form is valid
        // save data and redirect to thank you page
        redirect('thank_you_page');
    } else {
        // we have errors
        // redirect to specific error section
        // get first error element
        $ordered_required_inputs = array(
            'fname', 'lname', 'pnric'
        );
        $section_err = '';
        foreach ($ordered_required_inputs as $key => $input_name) {
            if (form_error($input_name) != ''){
                $section_err = '#'.$input_name;
                break;
            }
        }
        redirect('same_page'.$section_err);
    }

}
```

**Edit 3**

Please take into consideration that after redirection, `set_value` will not work because **set_value** requires that the form validation ran in the same context... you lose this context when you redirect.

To go to the specific input section without lose the previously entered data, you need to use client side validation instead of server side validation. This [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) will help you to make validation before submitting the page.

Comment: exactly same my approach is working but when form get multiple blank values then how to pass that id in redirect one by one, So that form load particular section and input.

Comment: please add the page logic, form content, section to see the logic

Comment: Please check the description

Comment: yess..Thank you so much for your answer. It worked :) Really appropriate your effort @vasilenicusor